# Getting id of accordion at specified index

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

This a variation I have asked before.

With the Bootstrap accordion,how can I retrieve the id of the panel at a specified index(index 0 for example)?

was thinking something along the lines of

```
var id = $('#accordion .in').get(0).attr("id");
```

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** selector in jquery.

```
var id = $('#accordion .in').eq(0).attr("id");
```